# Exclude logs from fluentd using exclude directive not working

Tags: fluentd, fluent-docker

Trying to exclude logs using the `grep`'s `exclude` directive.

```xml
<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.**>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key kubernetes.pod_name
    pattern /^podname-*/
  </exclude>
</filter>
```

I tried with different key names e.g. `container` and `namespace` as well. I am trying to exclude logs from a certain pod using the `pattern` but it's not working. Using type forward source type to send logs.

Want to exclude logs from certain pods starting with the same name from var log containers.

Comment: Please add sample names to your questions that you want to exclude and include.

Comment: Hi, like to exclude logs from pods like sytem-* , rest need to be parsed as they should be

Comment: Hi! Please try: `pattern /system-.*/` in the `exclude` section. Example: https://regex101.com/r/UFNW8l/1

Comment: Hi, Tried no luck. Will try to change key names and check once

Comment: Hi, No luck

Comment: Have you deployed `fluentd` as a DaemonSet? What kind of deployment do you have exactly? Please add this information to your question. If it's possible, please create a small repo (or post everything here) containing the deployment to reproduce this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find solution this situation?